# Best way to replace a whitespace when passing a value to a REST call in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I am passing a value from the database to a REST call and the REST call has an issue whenever the value has a whitespace. For example

```
"my test"
```

does not work, it needs to be

```
"my%20test"
```

So I did

```
'parameter=' || REPLACE(get_value_from_db('TEST'), CHR(32), '%20')
```

And it works but I hate hardcoding it like this and ope there is a better way

Comment: utl_url.escape('your text here')